# What is the program that suggests installable packages?

Tags: bash, apt

One of the features of Ubuntu that I really like is the one that suggests packages to install if you try to run a program that isn't installed, like this:

```
$ nmap
The program 'nmap' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Is that a fancy feature of Bash? An extra daemon that hides in the background? How does it do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[command-not-found](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/command-not-found) is the package you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an addition to the previous answer:

To switch this off for your own account (without deinstalling the whole package and so disabling this for ALL users), you may just add the following line to your own ~/.bashrc:

```
unset command_not_found_handle
```

This reverts to the default bevaviour of bash (see /etc/bash.bashrc for the definition of the function command_not_found_handle: it calls command-not-found if it is installed, otherwise it prints the default "command not found" error message).